# Datagridview returning null value

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have a form called "lookuptable" inside that form there is a datagridview "dgv1". I inserted "lookuptable" inside my main form "dashboard" using a panel "panel3".

Here is the code:

```
 Private Sub btnPOS_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPOS.Click
    TabControl1.SelectedTab = POS
    Dim f As New LookUpTable With {.TopLevel = False, .AutoSize = False}
    f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Me.Panel3.Controls.Add(f)
    f.Show()
End Sub
```

I am trying to get the value of cell number 5, but I get this error *System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'*

Here is the code I use to get the value:

```
 Private Sub CustomPrice_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PriceTxtBox.Text = LookUpTable.dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value
    'KeyPreview = True
End Sub
```

Dgv1 cell 5 has data. So why is it returning null?

Comment: You will likely find it's zero indexed.  ie 0 -> 4 rather than 1 -> 5

Comment: "I inserted "lookuptable" inside my main form". Why? Please acquaint yourself with user controls.

Comment: @John why what?

Comment: @Hursey I do know this. I tried every cell and it still returned null. Also every cell in my datagridview is populated, so there is no reason it should return nothing.

Comment: You may want to note that the form you are creating in the first code snippet… `Dim f As New LookUpTable With {.TopLevel = False, .AutoSize = False}` … is “local” to that method. The form is shown and may have data in the grid, HOWEVER… when execution gets to the line of code in the second code snippet… `PriceTxtBox.Text = LookUpTable.dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value.ToString()` … then… `LookUpTable` is NOT the “same” form created in the previous snippet of code. So, chances are good that the `LookUpTable` form in the second code snippet may not have a grid or rows since it is not shown.

Comment: The point is that the `LookUpTable` in the first code snippet is NOT the same form in the second code snippet. In the second snippet of code `LookUpTable` is the CLASS itself… and is NOT an “instantiated” `LookUpTable` form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, the current problem you have is because when the code creates the `LookUpTable` `f` form in the first code snippet with…

```
Dim f As New LookUpTable With {.TopLevel = False, .AutoSize = False}
```

Then `f` is LOCAL to that method. So, when the code gets to the second code snippet… it is NOT going to know about the form `f`… in other words, if we tried to access the form `f` in the second snippet of code with the line…

```
PriceTxtBox.Text = f.dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value.ToString()
```

The compiler will complain that it does not know what `f` is…

Therefore, one possible solution (not necessarily the best solution) is to make `f` a global variable like…

```
Dim f As LookUpTable
```

Then change the other snippets of code like below.

```
Private Sub btnPOS_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPOS.Click
  TabControl1.SelectedTab = POS
  f = New LookUpTable With {.TopLevel = False, .AutoSize = False}
  f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
  Me.Panel3.Controls.Add(f)
  f.Show()
End Sub
```

It is unclear where the code below is called as it appears to be a `Load` event. However, if it is in the same form as the code above then this should work…

```
Private Sub CustomPrice_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  PriceTxtBox.Text = f.dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value
  'KeyPreview = True
End Sub
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thank you @JohnG ! This makes sense, I did suspect it had to do with `f` being local. The code with the `Load event` is a different form, however I still managed to make it work. I also saw your profile, I noticed that you're from ep. I am also in ep, its great to see people from here on this site helping out.